# AVAsset failing to import due to damaged video. Error catching?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avasset

I'm combining videos using `AVFoundation` and have came across a video that appears to have a corrupt timescale. This video is creating an error when hitting "Choose" in the `UIImagePickerController`. The system error prints as soon as the "Choose" button is hit, but the app crash doesn't occur until the commented line below. The crash happens when it loads the asset, which cannot be loaded, as it is a nil value.

How do I catch this error to notify the user of the issue and prevent a crash?

> 2017-07-31 14:22:18.284542-0500 APP[2299:62163] [Generic] Video export failed for asset : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11821 "Cannot Decode" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Decode, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The media data could not be decoded. It may be damaged.}

```
   extension videoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let mediaInfo = info

    print("Media Info: ", mediaInfo)

    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
//ERROR THROWS AT BELOW LINE
        let avAsset = AVAsset(url:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL)
        //var message = ""
        if loadingAssetOne {
            //message = "Video one loaded"
            firstAsset = avAsset
        } else {
            //message = "Video two loaded"
            secondAsset = avAsset
            //set bg image

            videoPreviewUIImage(assetName: avAsset as! AVURLAsset)
        }
        //let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Asset Loaded", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        //alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
        //present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: check the URL before force unwrapping it

Comment: Try to get UIImagePickerControllerRefernceURL instead.